# strange redefined symbols

Tags: c++, include, compiler-errors

I included this header into one of my own: http://codepad.org/lgJ6KM6b
When I compiled I started getting errors like this:

```
CMakeFiles/bin.dir/SoundProjection.cc.o: In function `Gnuplot::reset_plot()':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/new:105: multiple definition of `Gnuplot::reset_plot()'
CMakeFiles/bin.dir/main.cc.o:project/gnuplot-cpp/gnuplot_i.hpp:962: first defined here
CMakeFiles/bin.dir/SoundProjection.cc.o: In function `Gnuplot::set_smooth(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)':
project/gnuplot-cpp/gnuplot_i.hpp:1041: multiple definition of `Gnuplot::set_smooth(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
CMakeFiles/bin.dir/main.cc.o:project/gnuplot-cpp/gnuplot_i.hpp:1041: first defined here
CMakeFiles/bin.dir/SoundProjection.cc.o:/usr/include/eigen2/Eigen/src/Core/arch/SSE/PacketMath.h:41: multiple definition of `Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotFileName'
```

I know it's hard to see in this mess, but look at where the redefinitions are taking place. They take place in files like /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.3.4/include/g++-v4/new:105. How is the new operator getting information about a gnuplot header? I can't even edit that file. How could that ever even be possible? I'm not even sure how to start debugging this. I hope I've provided enough information. I wasn't able to reproduce this in a small project. I mostly just looking for tips on how to find out why this is happening, and how to track it down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're obviously violating the "one definition rule". You have lots of definitions in your header file. Some of them are classes or class templates (which is fine), some of them are inline functions or function templates (which is also fine) and some of them are "normal" functions and static members of non-templates (which is not fine).

```
class foo;       // declaration of foo
class foo {      // definition of foo
   static int x; // declaration of foo::x
};

int foo::x;      // definition of foo::x

void bar();      // declaration
void bar() {}    // definition
```

The one definition rule says that your program shall contain at most one definition of an entity. The exceptions are classes, inline functions, function templates, static members of class templates (I probably forgot something). For those entities multiple definitions may exist as long as no two definitions of the same entity are in the same translation unit. So, including this header file into more than one translation unit leads to multiple definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you include conflicting headers. Try to check your include paths. They usually are defined in `-I` directive (at least in gcc) or in an environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Reading compiler errors usually helps. You should learn to understand what the compiler is telling you. The fact that it is complaining about a symbol being redefine is saying that you are breaking the One Definition Rule. Then it even tells you what the symbols are:

```
class GnuPlot {
//...
   GnuPlot& reset_plot(); // <-- declaration
//...
};
//...
Gnuplot& Gnuplot::reset_plot() { // <-- Definition
    nplots = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

You can declare a symbol as many times as you wish within a program, but you can only define it once (unless it is inlined). In this case the `reset_plot` is compiled and defined in all translation units that include the header, violating the One Definition Rule.

The simplest way out of it is declaring it inline, so that it can appear in more than one compilation unit and let the linker remove the redundant copies (if any) later on.

A little more problematic are the static members that must be declared within the class and defined (only once) in a translation unit. For that you can either create a .cpp file to define those variables (and any function/method that you don't need inlined in the header).